# Javascript - CryptoJS is not defined

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

justing any help/suggestions with a continuous issue I've been having throughout the entirety of today. I've gone to almost every other possible forum available to try and find a fix, but I'm still having no form of luck whatsoever. From some other discussions on the topic, I've pulled the following simple script to test the it's functionality (both with local files and via the online src), but still am being prompted with "Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined". Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/aes-min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "My Secret Passphrase");
        var decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedAES, "My Secret Passphrase");
        var plaintext = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    </script>
```

Comment: the clue is in `components` ... you've loaded the AES component of CryptoJS, but no CryptoJS

Comment: You are only adding the `aes.min.js`. Add the relevant crypto js file from components folder. May be this might help. Add this file as well `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/crypto-js.min.js` in a script tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but:

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
console.log(hashInBase64); // qnR8UCqJggD55PohusaBNviGoOJ67HC6Btry4qXLVZc=
```

Works fine in node.js.